# Trying to develop auditing program

Tags: powershell, csv, vbscript, audit

I've compiled this auditing program a while back when I was working as an IT for my local university and I'm quite stuck with actually grabbing the current working drive and pulling all of the files from **Programs** and **Programs x86** to successfully to build this application, instead of using the registry (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall) because that doesn't pull all of the programs only some.

Also, I'm unsure of how about getting the current active directory drive where the script is located originally on the second bolded part and make a folder in which it saves the file as the msinfo32.exe system name into a new folder.

(It doesn't matter what the name is) this is a long-term goal in which I have been trying to accomplish and I'm absolutely lost.

```
' Sample VBScript to Export list of Installed Programs into CSV File.
' ------------------------------------------------------
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim strComputer, strKeyPath
strComputer = "."

' Registry key path of Control panel items for installed programs

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Dim objReg, strSubkey, arrSubkeys 

Set objReg=GetObject( _ 
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
   strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 

Dim objFSO, objCSVFile

' Create CSV file 
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Here, I have given CSV file path as "Installed-Softwares.csv", this will create Installed-Softwares.csv file
' where you placed and execute this VB Script file. You can give your own file path
' like "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Installed-Softwares.csv"

Set objCSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("F:\Custom\Installed-Softwares.csv", _ 
    ForWriting, True)**

' Write Software property names as CSV columns(first line)
 objCSVFile.Write "Name,Version,Publisher,Location,Size"
 objCSVFile.Writeline ' New Line

Dim Name,Version,Publisher,Location,Size

'Enumerate registry keys.
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
 objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayName" , Name
 If Name <> "" Then 
    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayVersion", Version
           objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "Publisher",Publisher
           objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "InstallLocation", Location
           objReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "EstimatedSize" , Size
  If  Size <> "" Then 
   Size= Round(Size/1024, 3) & " MB"
  Else 
   Size= "0 MB"
  End If 

objCSVFile.Write Name &","&Version&","&Publisher&","&Location&","&Size
           objCSVFile.Writeline ' New Line
      End If 
Next

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: For example, pull from (C:\ for example or current main drive) program files and program files x86 -> put into list -> output Currentdrive:\newfolder\msinfo32systemname.

Also, it's displaying 0 MB instead of the actual MB, I noticed the output file is doing this. This works in conjuction with other files, in no means did I actually code this entirely from scratch.

Credit: https://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/VBScript-to-Get-List-of-Installed-Software-through-Registry.html

Comment: If you're using PSv5+, can you not just use something like `Get-Package | Sort Name | Export-Csv C:\temp\installedItems.csv -NoTypeInformation`?

Comment: As for the `Size` issue: `objReg.GetDWORDValue` gets a numeric value. You are comparing it to a string with `If  Size <> "" Then`. Change that to `If  Size <> 0 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tagging this as Powershell, here's a function you can use to find installed software on (remote) computer(s). It uses the registry, but looks for software in both `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

```
# Get the current path this script is in
$ScriptPath = if ($PSScriptRoot) { $PSScriptRoot } else { Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }
# Combine to make a valid path for the output file
$OutputPath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptPath -ChildPath 'InstalledSoftware'
if (!(Test-Path -Path $OutputPath -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $OutputPath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}


function Get-InstalledSoftware {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$NamePattern = '*',

        [switch]$ExcludeUpdates
    )
    begin {
        $UninstallPaths = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\',
                          'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\'
    }
    process {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
            $result = @()
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($computer) -or $computer -eq '.') { $computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME }
            $loggedOnUser = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer).UserName
            $regBaseKey   = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$computer)
            foreach ($regPath in $UninstallPaths) {
                ($regBaseKey.OpenSubKey($regPath)) | foreach {
                    $_.GetSubKeyNames() | ForEach-Object {
                        $regSubKey   = $regBaseKey.OpenSubKey("$regPath$_")
                        $application = $regSubKey.GetValue('DisplayName')
                        $size        = [int64]$regSubKey.GetValue('EstimatedSize')
                        if (($application) -and ($application -like $NamePattern)) {
                            if (!$ExcludeUpdates -or ($application -notlike "*update*")) {
                                $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    'Computer'        = $computer
                                    'Application'     = $application
                                    'Version'         = $regSubKey.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                                    'InstallLocation' = $regSubKey.GetValue('InstallLocation')
                                    'UninstallString' = $regSubKey.GetValue('UninstallString')
                                    'Publisher'       = $regSubKey.GetValue('Publisher')
                                    'Size'            = '{0:F2} MB' -f ($size / 1MB)
                                    'LoggedOnUser'    = $loggedOnUser
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        # close $regSubKey
                        if ($regSubKey)  { $regSubKey.Close() }
                    }
                }
            }
            # close $regBaseKey
            if ($regBaseKey)  { $regBaseKey.Close() }

            # export the software list for this computer as CSV
            $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath "msinfo32$computer"
            ($result | Sort-Object -Property 'Application' -Unique) | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation

            # show on screen
            Write-Verbose "Created '$outputFile'"
        }
    }
}
```

It creates a folder in the current script path called 'InstalledSoftware' where the csv file per computer is saved as 'msinfo32COMPUTERNAME.csv'

Call it like this for the local computer:

```
Get-InstalledSoftware -NamePattern * -ExcludeUpdates -Verbose
```

or feed it an array of computer names (you have admin permissions on) like this:

```
Get-InstalledSoftware -ComputerName machine1,machine2,machine3 -NamePattern * -ExcludeUpdates -Verbose
```